# Error occured while creating android subproject, Cordova, PhoneGap on Ubuntu

Tags: android, node.js, ubuntu, cordova

I'm trying to solve an issue with PhoneGap/Cordova on Ubuntu. After 2 days of searching on the net I tried everything that I can imagine.
- updated node.js to last version
- aliased nodejs to node
- updated PATH
- installed a lot of other things

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

 /home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
 Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
      at /home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
      at _rejected
      (/home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
      at /home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
      at Promise.when      
      (/home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
      at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch 
      (/home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
      at /home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
      at flush 
      (/home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: Do you have the Android SDK installed and it's location present in your path?

Comment: it seems the sdk is detected (otherwise you wouldn't see "using local environment") but maybe something from the sdk is missing. Have you run the sdk manager at least once and installed an android api and platform tools?

Comment: @Munim Yes, I have everything in place.

Comment: @QuickFix Yes, I did. I actually made some deploys to my android device without phonegap(app programmed in Java).